# Ending Skype call from keyboard

Tags: skype

I like to use the keyboard exclusively without touching the mouse. How can I end a Skype call without touching the mouse?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Also what version of the Skype client?

Comment: 4.2, Windows XP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the latest Skype version (5+), you can go to **Options > Advanced > Hotkeys.** Check off the "Enable Keyboard Shortcuts" box, then check "Hang up", and set it to the key you want.

This is for Windows. I am not sure the status of the Linux or Mac ones, but I believe they should have similar function as the Windows version has had this a long time.